# How to efficiently create patches of an image, with the patch object containing the coordinates of that patch in original image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, scikit-image

I have an image which I'm loading into python, and I need to segment the image into overlapping patches which I'm able to do with sklearn and skimage. However the functions for this only output patches but don't store the coordinate position of where this patch stemmed from in the original image.

I'm not using this to reassemble the image, as I know that can be done using another function.

Goal:

```
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib import pyplot


# load image as pixel array
img = image.imread('kolala.jpeg') #img.shape = (2000,1000)

# Outputs a stacked numpy array of patches
patches = sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d(img, patch_dim=(40,30))

# Ideally want something like

patches , coords = get_patches_and_coords_function(img, patch_dim=(40,30)


print(coords)

[{x_top: 0, y_top:1000, w:30, h:40},{},...]
```

Answer (score 1):

`extract_patches_2d` generates patches for each position on the image from the top left corner - if a patch of `patch_size` can be cropped on the image.

Here is a visual example for a small (meaningless) image.
The input image:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

img = load_sample_image("flower.jpg")[:15, :20, 0]
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

The generated patches:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image

patches = image.extract_patches_2d(img, patch_size=(10, 10))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 11, figsize=(11, 6), tight_layout=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.reshape(-1)):
    ax.imshow(patches[i], vmin=img.min(), vmax=img.max())
    ax.axis("off")
```

[image]

So the positions of the patches can be computed with:

```
import numpy as np

im_H, im_W = img.shape[:2]
p_H, p_W = patch_size

y = np.arange(0, im_H - (p_H - 1))
x = np.arange(0, im_W - (p_W - 1))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
positions = np.dstack((X, Y)).reshape(-1, 2)
```

Here are the positions on the image

```py
plt.imshow(img)
plt.scatter(*positions.T, s=10, c="red")
```

[image]